# Inserting Object at Specific Index of ArrayList Without Growing the Capacity of that ArrayList - Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList:

```
List<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>(M);
```

At some point in my code I add a new integer value at this array list at a specific index:

```
array.add(index, value);
```

The documentation says for that method:

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list (optional operation). Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).

and that's fine because that is what I actually want to do. The problem is that any time I do this, the size of my array grows by 1. That is, initially I had an array with size M filled in with zeroes. When I add the first value at index 0, I have this value there and M zero values, resulting in an array of size M + 1. When I add the second value at index 0, I have this value at index 0, the previous value shifted to the right at index 1, and M zero values, resulting in an array of size M + 2 etc.

My question is, how to add an element at a specific index of my arraylist (in my case, at index 0) shifting the previous elements by 1 index without exceeding the predefined capacity of the arraylist?

(I have to say, ArrayList is one of the most common structures in Java and yet one of the most confusing for me ...)

EDIT: I have to note that initially I fill in my arraylist with M zero values using a for loop, therefore I have e.g. for M = 5 an arraylist like this. [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: "When I add the first value at index 0, I have this value there and M zero values, resulting in an array of size M + 1" - wrong, you have an arrayList of size 1. Capacity and size are not the same thing in array List.

Comment: You're again confused between Capacity and Size. `M` is capacity, and not size. Please don't consider an `ArrayList` the same way you consider an array. They are 2 different things.

Comment: @RohitJain     Maybe you are right, but actually at the beginning of my code I fill in my arraylist with M zero values (using a for loop) and when I print the arraylist in order to test what happens in my code I indeed get an arraylist with M zeroes. That is, if e.g. M = 5 I get [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]. Therefore, the current array size is equal to the capacity M. Isn't that right?

Comment: @Kotsos But why are you inserting `M` zeroes, when ultimately you're replacing them? It would be even better to explain what are you trying to do, for which you're doing this?

Comment: @RohitJain     That's a perfectly valid and right to the point question! I had a reason to do that though. I want to simulate a cache replacement algorithm. I have a cache (arraylist) of size M and N > M items available for caching. I have two ArrayList<Integer>, both of size N: one for keeping the score of the items and another where I put the ID of the items according to their position: if the item is in the cache, its ID will be placed at this positions arraylist at the same index as in the cache (which will be 0 < index < M-1). Otherwise, I will put positions.add(M, ID). (to be continued)

Comment: @RohitJain When I have a request for an item, its score is increased by 1 as follows: I have a local integer variable score inside my incScore method and I do: int score = scorelist.get(positions.indedOf(ID)); Then I do score += 1; and finally I place the updated score again in my list: scorelist.add(positions.indexOf(ID), score); That is why I wanted to have an initial zero value.

Comment: @Kotsos Why are you not using an array then?

Comment: @RohitJain     I wasn't sure what to do to be honest. I created a plan (like pseudocode) of what I have to do and I thought due to the complexity of the code (many methods - insertion, lookup, replacement, update of scores, printing, reordering of the cache list due to a cache hit etc.) it would be beneficial to take advantage of a data structure such as ArrayList and its build-in methods such as add, remove etc.

Comment: For whatever purpose you've shown in comments, an array and `ArrayList` give same performance. The only usage of `ArrayList` comes when you don't know a fixed size for your array, and that is supposed to grow. If the size is fixed, go for an array. Or may be you can describe your real problem, so that we can suggest some better data structure.

Comment: @RohitJain     Well, pretty much that is the concept. I want to simulate a web caching algorithm that will perform better than LRU but will be at least as fast as LRU. Therefore, I have a cache of size M and a window of last K requests. Every time a web object is requested, its score (request count) increases by 1. When a request for an object is dropped of the window, the score of that object is decreased by 1. When the cache is full and there is a cache miss for  an object, that object will replace the "least-valuable" cached object if its score is at least equal with that object. (cont'ed)

Comment: @RohitJain     The important thing is that I maintain the cache partially sorted according to the score of the objects and the time-of-access (which is implicitly given by the window, no need for timestamps). Therefore, there is no need for "for loops" to find the item to be evicted from the cache in order to be replaced by a new item: it will always be the right-most item in the cache list. Now, I have an arraylist of max size N (equal to the number of all items) to keep the score and another one where I put the numeric ID of that items (an integer from 1 to N) according to their (continued)

Comment: @Kotsos You should post this as a different question. That would be better.

Comment: @RohitJain     in the cache (i.e. 0 < index < M-1) or at positions.add(M, ID) if the item is not in the cache. My university prof. suggested the use of arrays since then he assumes that the simulation time will be as low as the one when simulating LRU. Thus, we will have much better hit rate than LRU and processing time similar to LRU at the same time! That's the whole concept.

Comment: @RohitJain Ok, I will. I didn't so far because I try to keep my questions small and specific to help others to help me, and something like that might be very general.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the last element of the list and then insert. This will keep size unchanged

Comment: Hey, that sounds a good idea! And a simple one ... I will try this and give a feedback, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you want to add values at a specific index in arraylist without increasing its length , it is better to use set method from arraylist.
Use
ArrayList.set(int index, E element)

Answer (score 0):

You must use set method instead of add methods i.e. `array.set(index, value);`.